# Nested async/await usage

Tags: javascript

Given the example below, if I wanted to `await` `player.play()`, do I have to add `async` in TWO places since `foo` will ultimately be the executed function?

example:

```
const foo = (player) => {

    let foo = videojs;

    foo.addEventListener('ready', () => {
       player.play()
    }

}
```

would it be:

```
const foo = async (player) => {

    let foo = videojs;

    foo.addEventListener('ready', async () => {
       await player.play()
    }

}

await foo();
```

or:

```
const foo = (player) => {

    let foo = videojs;

    foo.addEventListener('ready', async () => {
       await player.play()
    }

}

foo();
```

Comment: Don't mark a function as async if it doesn't await something. Since `foo` doesn't await, it shouldn't be async.

Comment: Neither of these functions should be `async` or should use `await`. `foo` is binding an event handler. There is nothing to `await`. The handler could `await player.play()` but since there is no statement after that function call, there is no reason to do that either.

Comment: @FelixKling @404. sorry, I fixed my example.  I meant to add `await` before both instances of `player.play()`

Answer (score 3):

If you want `foo` to return a promise that resolves when the `.play()`-returned promise resolves, then you could promisify `addEventListener`.

Something like this:

```
const whenEvent = (elem, event) => new Promise((resolve) =>
    elem.addEventListener(event, resolve, { once: true })
);

const foo = async (player) => {
    await whenEvent(videojs, 'ready');
    await player.play();
};

foo().then(() => console.log("foo resolved"));
```

Note that a promise can only resolve once, while an event listener can be called multiple times. So this promisified version (`whenEvent`) will only capture the first event, and then stop listening. `whenEvent` (and thus `foo`) should be called again to deal with a next occurrence of the event.

Comment: Alternatively, use `.addEventListener(event, resolve, {once: true})`

Comment: Updated! Thanks, @Bergi.